# I'm getting the broken links only on the specified single page. Is there a way to find the broken links on the sitemap.xml file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bootstrap-5

//This code is attached. Only the broken links on the provided url are displayed to us; I required it for the entire website. I'm getting the broken links on the specified single page. Is there a way to find the broken links on the sitemap.xml file using node.js?

```
const express = require('express')
 
const {exec} = require('child_process')
 
const app = express ()
 
const bodyparser = require('body-parser')
 
app.use(bodyparser.json())
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:false}))
 
app.set('view engine','ejs')
 
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('brokenlinkchecker',{title:'broken link checker',info:''})
})
 
app.post('/brokenlinkchecker',(req,res)=>{
 
exec('brkn '+ req.body.url + ' --verbose',(err,stdout,stderr) => {
    if(err){
        res.send(err)
    }
    
    console.log(stdout)
 
    res.render('brokenlinkchecker',{title:'broken link checker',info:stdout})
})
})
app.listen(5000)
```

//Front End Part

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Broken Link Checker</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1 class="text-center" style="color: #fe620a;">
                Broken Link checker
            </h1>
            <br>
            <form action="/brokenlinkchecker" method="post">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="url">Website URL:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="url" required placeholder="Enter URL" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-block" style="background-color: #fe620a;">
                        Get Broken Links
                    </button>                 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="links">Broken Links:</label>
                    <textarea readonly class="form-control" placeholder="broken links" cols="30" rows="10"> <%= info %></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</html>
```